# How do you call a JavaScript (AJAX) function when the user reaches the end of a page to load new content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom

On twitter (new twitter) and facebook they now have the the ability to load new tweets and posts when you hit the bottom of the page..

Is there a JavaScript / jQuery event that you can call / add to a div so when the browser hits the bottom it does some ajax call to get the new data?

Thanks

Daniel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a jQuery plugin for that: [Infinite Scroll jQuery Plugin](http://www.infinite-scroll.com/infinite-scroll-jquery-plugin/).

And here's the description of the pattern that it implements: [The Interaction Design Pattern](http://www.infinite-scroll.com/the-interaction-design-pattern/).

Comment: @Daniel Upton: I'm glad the answer was helpful. You may want to mark it as "accepted" by clicking on the green tick on the left, it you think it is the best answer for your question.

Answer (score 1):

It's called "Lazy Loading"

a plugin for jquery: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

in fact there are many plugins: http://www.google.com/search?q=lazy+loading+jquery

googling for Lazy Loading will help you a load :) 
http://www.google.com/search?q=lazy+loading

Comment: A different version of Lazy Loading not the conventional one.

Answer (score 1):

It's called **Infinite Scrolling**, and there's a jQuery plugin for it here: http://www.infinite-scroll.com/